# Image widget crop not returning multiple derivatives in JSON API

Tags: 8, media

I'm using below modules for image crop

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/image_widget_crop
https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudinary
https://www.drupal.org/project/consumers
https://www.drupal.org/project/consumer_image_styles
https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi
```

Returning data in JSON API.

Using multiple paragraphs for images. I have 1 image as logo & 1 image as content.

For 1 image it's showing correct image width & height, X & Y co-ordinates (derivatives).

But for multiple image it copy same height, width, x, y co-ordinates to other images.

So it's not showing image wise derivatives for multiple images.

Once image is uploaded it saved to cloudinary.

```
{
"meta": {
"derivatives": {
"box": "http://res.cloudinary.com/XXX/image/upload/s--CJHoE3mM--/c_crop,h_400,w_400,x_29,y_46/test.jpg?itok=4GARJEFS",
"thumbnail": "http://res.cloudinary.com/XXX/image/upload/s--vlxu-1hL--/c_fit,h_100,w_100/test.jpg?itok=hed-1-Mh",
"wide": "http://res.cloudinary.com/XXX/image/upload/s--4-Vk3FhO--/c_crop,h_200,w_356,x_76,y_86/test.jpg?itok=GOzme5ht"
}
}
```

Does anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code

```
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;


$filed_images = $paragraphs->get('field_image')->getValue();
 $images =[];
 foreach ($filed_images as $image) {
            $images[] = ImageStyle::load('273x273')
              ->buildUrl(File::load($image['target_id'])
                ->getFileUri());
          }
```

Comment: It's loading image style for another image as well. But it's same value